# window.onload doesn't work within Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm working on an issue for the 2048 game which is a webapp that's been ported to Android:

[https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android/issues/15](https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android/issues/15/)

The JavaScript seems to work everywhere except for a button that toggles a style change in the app.  The JavaScript works in a browser, just not in the app.  I think it comes down to some code in nightmode.js which begins:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("night");
    a.onclick = function() {<<code that toggles day and night colors>>}
```

Does anyone have a solution to why this JavaScript isn't getting run?

Edit: When on Desktop Chrome and the screen is resized all the way down, the button continues to work.  But switching the device mode in Chrome reveals that the thing never works for mobile devices.  Since this behavior happens even without the WebView, it looks like just a javascript problem now.

Comment: Excuse me, have you checked if you allowed js and DOM to run inside your webview?

Comment: It maybe that it is still loading some item. you could try window.document.onload

Comment: @statosdotcom Yup.  The entire game is JavaScript.  This is the only functionality that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onload` event is fired when *everything* is loaded. This can take some time.
Plus, `window.onload` might get overwritten later on...

You can try this instead:

```
var ready = function ( fn ) {

  // Sanity check
  if ( typeof fn !== 'function' ) return;

  // If document is already loaded, run method
  if ( document.readyState === 'complete'  ) {
    return fn();
  }

  // Otherwise, wait until document is loaded
  // The document has finished loading and the document has been parsed but sub-resources such as images, stylesheets and frames are still loading. The state indicates that the DOMContentLoaded event has been fired.
  document.addEventListener( 'interactive', fn, false );

  // Alternative: The document and all sub-resources have finished loading. The state indicates that the load event has been fired.
  // document.addEventListener( 'complete', fn, false );

};

// Example
ready(function() {
    // Do night-mode stuff...
});
```

see: http://gomakethings.com/a-native-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-method/